# Angular 5 Global Import & Constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

I would just like to know if it possible to import & construct something globally for all components to use. Currently I have to import & construct my shared service in almost all of my components, which I feel is quite bad.

Example of my import & constructor that gets copy-pasted in almost every of my 20 components:

```
import { SharedService } from 'path'
...
constructor (private SharedService : SharedService) {}
```

Comment: No not possible

Comment: _"which I feel is quite bad."_  Actually, having a global variable would be bad. And using this service in most of your components is probably bad, so you might want to rethink your design.